# Dynamic Input in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm new for spring and I try to develop little application using spring. As I learn in spring provide values for the properties using xml file. I want to give values in run time as below in java.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = num.nextInt(); //dynamic value 
    }
 }
```

How can I achieve this in spring.Try to google and find. But unable to get a solution.

Comment: You can go through this Sprring Boot deocumentataion about externalizing configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @Lasa would you like to take dynamic data from the Properties file.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri any how I want to take dynamic data. It is ok with property file also. Is there is way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 ) Please put the all Queries in Properties file 
2 ) Give the properties file Location

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:PropertiesFilename.properties");
```

3 ) Injecting a property with the @Value annotation

```
@Value( "${Property which is exists in properties file.}" )
private String yourVaraibleName;
```